# SwiftUI Webview using WKWebView is crasing with EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: ios, swiftui, crash, wkwebview, uiviewrepresentable

I have written a webview using UIViewRepresentable and WKWebView in SwiftUI.
The app is currently published in the app store. For some users, the app is crashing and we are not able to reproduce it.

**Below is the crash log:**

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000010455c388
    0  uMove                          0x28388 specialized WebView.makeUIView(context:) + 31 (WebView.swift:31)
    1  uMove                          0x27b48 protocol witness for UIViewRepresentable.makeUIView(context:) in conformance WebView + 4329765704 (<compiler-generated>:4329765704)
    2  SwiftUI                        0xaa4bc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_326 + 6512
    3  SwiftUI                        0x9ac5c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1106 + 1428
    4  SwiftUI                        0xca31a8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 8712
    5  SwiftUI                        0xca5868 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 18632
    6  SwiftUI                        0x89200 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_513 + 11236
    7  SwiftUI                        0xca306c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 8396
    8  SwiftUI                        0xca24b8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1 + 5400
    9  SwiftUI                        0x53eb00 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_5 + 26880
    10 AttributeGraph                 0x3ef8 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 512
```

Below is the code snippet where it is crashing:The crash is happening while returning WKWebView instance from makeUIView() function.

```swift
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var url: String
     
    private let wKWebView = WKWebView()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        configure(context: context)
        
        print(LOG_TAG, "makeUIView Webview loading url \(url)")
        if(!url.isEmpty) {
            wKWebView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string:url)!))
         }
        return wKWebView
    }
    
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> WebViewNavigationDelegate {
        WebViewNavigationDelegate(self)
    }
    
    // Our own methods
    func configure(context: Context) {
        wKWebView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        //wKWebView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        wKWebView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        
        wKWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        wKWebView.allowsLinkPreview = true
        
        wKWebView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        wKWebView.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
    }
    .....
    ....
    ....
}
```

Initially I thought the probem might be due to loading the URL inside the `makeUIView()` function considering the view might not be ready and we are trying to load. So I moved the loading URL logic to the `updateUIView` function, but no luck.